# Count for matching values

Tags: sql-server

I want to return any immediate that have a count greater than 3 when the immediate_id matches the start_id or the immediate_id matches the end_id.The start_id will either equal the end_id and have a count greater than 3 or the start_id will equal the immediate_id and have a count greater than 3. This right now is returning all matches for that specific immediate and not ones greater than 3 for that immediate. immediate has immediate_id, start has start_id, end has end_id and each immediate has a start and start_id with an end and end_id. I want only cases where immediate_id = start_id > 3 and immediate_id = end_id > 3.

```
select immediate
count(immediate) OVER (partition by start_id) as matchCount
from addresses where
start_id = end_id
or start_id = immediate_id
and year = 2016
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample and what would be the desired result from it please? Also how can `immediate_id = start_id > 3` AND `immediate_id = end_id > 3` at the same time?

Comment: That would imply that `start_id = end_id` and `> 3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `or` statement in Parentheses and actually add `> 3` to your where clause like this:

`where count(immediate) > 3 and (immediate_id = start_id or immediate_id = end_id)`